# How can i get total number of frames in swf file?

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

> i convert ppt to swf format, so i need to find total number of frames in that swf file, how to get it? and how to go the last frame of the given swf file?.
>
> example: here i given the source code for goto provious and next frame,but still i didn't get first frame, how can i get it? is there any solution guide me...
>
> **here How can i get total number of frames?** Please explain berifly... thanks in advance..

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function getFlashMovieObject(myFlashMovie)
{
if (window.document[myFlashMovie]) 
{
return window.document[myFlashMovie];
}
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
{
if (document.embeds && document.embeds[myFlashMovie])
  return document.embeds[myFlashMovie]; 
}
else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
{
return document.getElementById(movieName);
}
}

//for Previous frame.....
function PrevFrameFlashMovie()
{ 
var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("myFlashMovie");
var currentFrame=flashMovie.TGetProperty("/",4);
var nextFrame=parseInt(currentFrame);
var prevfram =nextFrame-4;
flashMovie.GotoFrame(prevfram);
flashMovie.Play();
}

//for Next frame.....
function PlayFlashMovie()
{
var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("myFlashMovie");
flashMovie.Play();
//embed.nativeProperty.anotherNativeMethod();
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" WIDTH="595" HEIGHT="460" id="myFlashMovie" style="background:#fff;">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="/file.swf"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=autolow >

<EMBED src="/file.swf" quality="autolow" wmode="transparent"  autoplay="false" WIDTH="595" HEIGHT="460" NAME="myFlashMovie" ALIGN="middle" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;"></EMBED>
<PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"/>     <param value="false" name="autoplay" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="True" />

</OBJECT>




<input type="button" onClick="PrevFrameFlashMovie();" value="PreviousFrame" name="Previous"> 

<input type="button" onclick="PlayFlashMovie();" name="Play" value="NextFrame >>"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

when the SWFs are loaded you can get total_no_of_frmaes using  **_totalframes** property.

```
var totalFrames=flashMovie._totalframes
```

Comment: For the first frame you can use GotoFrame(1)

Comment: but its not working.. the slider control goes frame1 but the slide not moved to the first slide..the current slide still hangging there, so that i have used play() function...